# Select column in pivot table output

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I want to select a column after I created a pivot table, but it is not working for me

The pivot table makes it multi-index, so I tried to work with reset_index en reset_index(inplace=True), but I don't understand what the reset does for the output

Create a table:

```
df = {'TYPE' : pd.Series(['Advisory','Advisory1','Advisory1','Advisory2','Advisory2','Advisory3','Advisory3']),
 'VALUE' : pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 4])}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Make pivot:

```
output = pd.pivot_table(df, ['VALUE'], ['TYPE'],aggfunc=[np.sum])
```

Reset index (without inplace is True) and select column:

```
output2 = output.reset_index()
output2['VALUE']
```

Reset index (with inplace is True) and select column:

```
output3 = output.reset_index(inplace=True)
output3['VALUE']
```

I expect to get the values of the column VALUE, but i get errors:

Output2: 'VALUE'

Output3: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: You can drop the level of the multi index check out `droplevel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is not to create the multiindex by passing your signle aggfunc with the brackets which creates a list.  Just pass the single function.

```
output = pd.pivot_table(df, 'VALUE', ['TYPE'], aggfunc=np.sum)

print(output)

           VALUE
TYPE            
Advisory       1
Advisory1      5
Advisory2      9
Advisory3      5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with: `output["sum"]["VALUE"]`

Answer (score 0):

you can access `VALUE` using tuples

```
output2[('sum', 'VALUE')]

0    1
1    5
2    9
3    5
```